# Ubuntu 18.04 Server sha256sum

Tags: server, 18.04, iso, sha256

I'm downloading an ISO image of Ubuntu 18.04 server AMD 64 bits from http://releases.ubuntu.com/bionic/

On that page two ISO images are found:

1. http://releases.ubuntu.com/bionic/ubuntu-18.04.1.0-live-server-amd64.iso
2. http://releases.ubuntu.com/bionic/ubuntu-18.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso

From that page, the file SHA256SUMS can be downloaded in order to check the integrity of the images.

The first one ( **18.04.1.0** ) is listed in SHA256SUMS file, and its checksum is OK.The second one ( **18.04.1** ) isn't listed there.

On the other hand, if you download an ISO image directly from the main Ubuntu web page ( https://www.ubuntu.com/#download ), an automatic download of the second one ( **18.04.1** ) is started.

My questions are the following ones:

1. Which is the latest release **18.04.1.0** or **18.04.1** ?
2. Where is the SHA256SUMS file containing the checksum of **18.04.1** release ?

Thanks for any clue.

Comment: Have you tried downloading both ISOs and comparing them (via `cmp iso1 iso2` or something)? I would guess one is just a hard or symlink to the other (for whatever reason, maybe a bug).

Comment: You are right ! I downloaded both and compared them with diff command. They are the same. Thanks !

Comment: Hey, thank you answering and trying so quickly. I just wanted to try myself but given my current download speed it would take ~20 minutes. To be really, really sure, you could also do `sha256sum iso1 iso2` and compare the checksums.

Comment: Thank you to give me that clue. It should be great if maintainers of Ubuntu release page commented that 18.04.1 release is only a hard link to 18.04.1.0 release in order to avoid confusion, or include both on SHA256SUMS file, so whatever image you download, checksum file contains it.